# Reciprocal of entire function

Tags: complex-analysis

In Liouville theorem exercise we often define a new function $g(z)=\frac{1}{f(z)}$, where $f(z)$ is an entire function.

Why is $g(z)$ entire? there can be some $z$'s such that $f(z)=0$.

Comment: What do you mean by "Liouville theorem exercise"?  A proof of Liouville's theorem?  Or, perhaps, some exercise where Liouville's theorem is to be used?  If you do not provide any context, it is improbable that you receive any answer.

Answer (score 1):

In this context $g(z)=\frac{1}{f(z)}$ is not always entire when $f(z)$ is entire. Take $f(z)=z$ as your entire function. Then $g(z)=\frac{1}{f(z)}=\frac{1}{z}$ is not entire, because it is not defined in $z=0$. Maybe you meant to say that $g(z)=\frac{1}{f(z)}$ is entire iff $f(z)$ is entire and does not have roots.

Comment: @YvesDaoust So... you think the function $z\mapsto1/(1-z)$ is entire?

Comment: $f(z)=1-z$ has $z=1$ as root. So if you read the above very carefully: for $\frac{1}{f(z)}$ to be entire, $f(z)$ has to be entire and **$f(z)$ may not have any roots.** For example, $\frac{1}{e^z}$ is entire for $e^z$ is entire and never equal to 0 (no roots).